# How to narrow a Rectangle within a Sprite to exclude transparent pixels?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a `Sprite` that contains opaque objects surrounded by transparent pixels. I also have a `Rectangle` that represents a part of the `Sprite` that I want to render using `BitmapData.draw()`.

The problem is that the `Rectangle` that I obtained also contains transparent parts. How can I narrow the `Rectangle` to only include the opaque parts and ignore the transparent surroundings?

kapep's answer is just what I want to do, but the problem is that the source is a `Sprite`, not a `BitmapData` object, and I don't have `getColorBoundsRect()` on a `Sprite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getColorBoundsRect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) for this.

```
var mask:uint = 0xFF000000; // ignore rgb, use alpha only
var transparent = 0x00000000; 
var rect:Rectangle = imageBitmapData.getColorBoundsRect(mask, transparent, false);
```

To operate with the pixels of the sprite, it needs to be drawn to a `BitmapData` first (use `BitmapData.draw`). Then after getting a smaller rectangle with `getColorBoundsRect`, create a new BitmapData with the dimensions of that rectangle. The last step is to use [copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29), to copy the area of the rectangle from first image to the new one.

```
var imageBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(image.width, image.height, true, 0);
imageBitmapData.draw(image);
// var rect =  ... as above
var resultBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width, rect.height, true, 0);
resultBitmapData.copyPixels(imageBitmapData, rect, new Point(0,0));
```

Comment: The problem is that the source is not a `BitmapData`, but a `Sprite`.

Comment: @Radu Updated my answer. I don't really see the difference to you original settings though, where you also just have a sprite and a rectangle. I think you can't avoid to create a second BitmapData object here.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, creating a second `BitmapData`. Thanks for the solution, I'll test to see if creating a `BitmapData` and using `copyPixels` is faster than just drawing the transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question a tad confusing, but if I do understand correctly, here's what you should do:

First, use `BitmapData.draw()` to take the "picture" of the Sprite, placing it in your new `BitmapData` instance.  Then, you need to find the boundaries of the transparent area.  Do this separately for each edge.  Starting at each edge, look at pixels on a regular interval (e.g. every 10 pixels) and see if they're all transparent.  If they are, move in towards the center by a certain number of pixels and repeat.  Here's some example code (not tested!):

```
// Bitmap data already exists
var bmd:BitmapData; // content already exists

var isTransparent:Function = function(bmd:BitmapData, x:uint, y:uint):Boolean
{
    var pixelValue:uint = bmd.getPixel32(0, 0);
    var alphaValue:uint = pixelValue >> 24 & 0xFF;
    return (alphaValue == 0);
};

// Look at right edge
var curX:uint = bmd.width-1;
var interval:uint = 10;
var iterations:uint = Math.ceil(bmd.height / interval);
var transparentX:uint = curX + 1;
var stillTransparent:Boolean = true;
while (stillTransparent)
{
   for (var i:uint=0; i<iterations; i++)
   {
      var curY:int = i * interval;
      if (!isTransparent(bmd, curX, curY))
      {
         stillTransparent = false;
         break;
      }
   }

   // If stillTransparent==true, this entire column was transparent.
   // Get ready for next loop by moving in [interval] pixels
   if (stillTransparent)
   {
      transparentX = curX
      curX -= interval; // check needed if may be completely transparent
   }   
}

// transparentX now represents the last known x value on 
// the right edge where everything was still transparent.
```

Finally, take the `x` and `y` results of the transparency boundary tests and use them to create a `Rectangle` and use `BitmapData.draw` to only copy the relevant non-transparent portion into a new `BitmapData` instance.

Comment: Caveat: This was an "off the top of my head" response.  I had forgotten about `getColorBoundsRect`, and depending on your needs that would probably be much more efficient.